# Efficient way of calculating time spent by machines in different states with a large dataset

Tags: sql, sql-server, qlikview

I'm having trouble figuring out a good approach to this problem. I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
MACHINE     DATETIME                 CODE  
C54118PC1   2016-04-01 00:00:01.000  10
C54118PC1   2016-04-01 00:01:12.000  4
C54118PC1   2016-04-01 00:01:36.000  10
C54118PC1   2016-04-01 00:01:50.000  4
C54123PC1   2016-04-01 00:00:02.000  0
C54123PC1   2016-04-01 01:00:02.000  0
```

Ultimately, I want to display this in a Qlikview document as a pie chart that shows how long a machine has spent in each state(code).

In order to do this, I think I need to get the data in this format:

```
MACHINE     DATE       CODE DURATION
Machine1    07/06/2016  2   07:30:14
Machine1    07/06/2016  5   02:45:10
Machine2    07/06/2016  0   12:37:05
Machine2    07/06/2016  5   04:04:59
Machine1    08/06/2016  2   02:57:13
Machine1    08/06/2016  4   04:12:05
Machine1    08/06/2016  5   03:07:12
Machine3    08/06/2016  8   02:49:23
```

This would be  1 row for each code, per day, per machine with the total duration for that day and code.

The other consideration is that this is a large dataset - there are currently at least 2 million rows and this is likely to grow quite quickly as more machines are added and more time passes.

So, basically I need a really efficient way of calculating the time spent in different states(codes), by machine and date. I'm thinking that this would be best done in SQL however I could also do it within Qlikview if this worked out to be more efficient. Can anyone help?

Thank you in advance!

EDIT: Sorry, I forgot to explain how the logging works! We have a bunch of machines that alternate between various states during the day (such as printing, idle, cleaning). Each time they change states (e.g. from printing to idle), they log a timestamp along with their new state.

(They also log timestamps and their current states at regular intervals, even if they haven't actually changed state.)

Duration is calculated as the time difference between two consecutive timestamps.

Comment: You're much more likely to get help by including your table structures as well as expected output **that matches your example data**. Also, this problem has been answered on this site before, so a quick search would likely find the answer for you.

Comment: I can't make heads or tails of this. How do you calculate duration? I think we need to seem some ddl and test data. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Thanks for the advice and the link! I'll bear it in mind next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```
Declare @Table table (machine varchar(25),DateTime datetime,Code int)
Insert into @Table (Machine,DateTime,Code) values 
('Machine1','2016-04-01 00:00:01.000',10),
('Machine1','2016-04-01 00:01:12.000',4),
('Machine1','2016-04-01 00:01:36.000',10),
('Machine1','2016-04-01 00:01:50.000',4),
('Machine2','2016-04-01 00:00:02.000',0),
('Machine2','2016-04-01 01:00:02.000',0),
('Machine1','2016-04-02 00:00:01.000',10),
('Machine1','2016-04-02 00:01:12.000',4),
('Machine1','2016-04-02 00:01:36.000',10),
('Machine1','2016-04-02 00:01:50.000',4),
('Machine2','2016-04-02 00:00:02.000',0),
('Machine2','2016-04-02 01:00:02.000',0)


IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#Temp1', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Temp1; 

-- Generate Date Range
Select Distinct DateR1=cast(DateTime as Date),DateR2=DateAdd(DD,1,cast(DateTime as Date)) into #Temp1 from @Table
Create Index idx on #Temp1 (DateR1,DateR2)

;with cteBase as (
        Select *
             ,MSDate1 = DateTime
             ,MSDate2 = Lead(DateTime,1,DateAdd(DD,1,cast(DateTime as Date)))  over (Partition by Machine Order by Machine,DateTime) 
         From @Table
      )
Select Machine
      ,Date = DateR1
      ,Code
      ,Duration = CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(SS, sum(DateDiff(SS,case when MSDate1<=DateR1 then DateR1 else MSDate1 end,case when MSDate2>DateR2 then DateR2 else MSDate2 end)), 0), 114)
 From #Temp1 A
 Join cteBase B on (MSDate1 between DateR1 and DateR2 or MSDate2 between DateR1 and DateR2)
 Group By Machine
      ,DateR1
      ,Code
```

Returns

```
Machine         Date        Code    Duration
Machine1        2016-04-01  4       23:58:34:000
Machine1        2016-04-01  10      00:01:25:000
Machine1        2016-04-02  4       23:58:35:000
Machine1        2016-04-02  10      00:01:25:000
Machine2        2016-04-01  0       23:59:58:000
Machine2        2016-04-02  0       00:00:00:000
```

Comment: This looks great - thank you! I just need to test it with my dataset. The last state of the day should be handled as you say - it would run until midnight and then that state would be the starting state for the next day (as machines could run continuously overnight). Is that / can that be handled by this method?

Comment: Sorry, I had a call.  And I spun myself around.   Is the time supplied the begin state or end state

Comment: No worries, I really appreciate your help! The time supplied is the beginning of the state.

Comment: Updated my answer.  See comments at top

Comment: I removed the need for UDFs.  I figured you data would contain all incremental dates

Comment: SO - the updated query appears to be totally accurate following testing which is great!!!! Interestingly though, it takes quite a bit longer to run than the original one. I tested them on the same dataset (2,312,060 rows) and the first one took 6 seconds (!) while the second one took 1 minute 17 seconds.

Comment: It's not a big issue as still a pretty short time considering the size of the data but it would still be interesting to test against your original method with the cte and the new case statements as a proper comparison.

Comment: Apologies for the performance, but the first one didn't include the logic to fill the gaps.  Even then, 2.1MM rows is not huge, and the performance is disappointing.   If you are not apposed to using #Temp tables, you may be able to gain significant improvements.    Let me know, happy to help

Comment: Yes, I thought that might be a large reason why... It's definitely worth exploring faster methods though as there is a chance that I'll be asked to open this up to some or all of our full dataset at some point which is currently around 450 million rows and growing exponentially!! I'm not fussed about using temp tables - the server is well specced and this will be the only query running. I was going to put it all into a stored proc eventually too. How would you suggest using them - would you put the sub selects into temp tables first? I know I keep saying it but thank you so much again!

Comment: Hold on, I'm creating a data set with 2.4MM rows to test performance

Comment: I created a data set with 2.2MM rows a  data ( sample data x 1,000 machines x 365 days).    I can't beat the 1 min 17 sec.  I dig the puzzle, so I'll noodle this for a bit. If I get some inspiration, I let you kno.

Comment: That's great! :-) It came back in 1 minute 6 seconds on mine so the third one did slice off about 11 seconds!!

Answer (score 0):

UNTESTED:
`LEAD()` An analytic (window function) that lets you look at the next ordered row value for a given partition of data seems like it would work...

So in this case: we want the datetime of the next row for a given machine regardless of state... Something like:

```
SELECT MACHINE
     , FORMAT(DATETIME, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
     , CODE
     , SUM(Lead(DateTIme) over (partition by Machine order by dateTime asc) - datetime) AS DURATION, 
FROM TABLENAME
GROUP BY MACHINE, CODE, FORMAT(DATETIME, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

I'm unsure abou the data math here to get duration.

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily achieved in QV itself (see the script below).

Regarding the data size. You can implement `Incremental Load` in QV and load only the new records when the app is reloaded and perform the transformation only on small set instead on the full dataset.

Example workflow will be: on every reload extract only the records for the last date, perform the transformation, load the previously transformed data from qvd and concatenate the new result to the qvd. This is very common approach with QV (I'm using this on daily basis). Usually i prefer this approach since im not pushing the database to do QV's work and avoiding conflicts with the DBAs ;)

If you want i can paste sample script with incremental load (just leave comment)

More details on incremental load:

- http://www.quickintelligence.co.uk/qlikview-incremental-load/
- http://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2014/09/qlikview-incremental-load/

Example script:

```
RawData:
Load
    MACHINE,  
//  DATETIME, // this is not needed anymore
    CODE,
    date(left(DATETIME, 10)) as Date, // extract the date
    mid(DATETIME, 12, 8) as Duration // extract the duration
; 
Load * Inline [
    MACHINE   , DATETIME                 , CODE  
    C54118PC1 , 2016-04-01 00:00:01.000  , 10
    C54118PC1 , 2016-04-01 00:01:12.000  , 4
    C54118PC1 , 2016-04-01 00:01:36.000  , 10
    C54118PC1 , 2016-04-01 00:01:50.000  , 4
    C54123PC1 , 2016-04-01 00:00:02.000  , 0
    C54123PC1 , 2016-04-01 01:00:02.000  , 0
];

Data:
Load
    interval(sum(Duration)) as TotalDuration, // sum the total duration and convert it to timestamp format
    MACHINE,  
    Date, 
    CODE
Resident
    RawData
Group By
    MACHINE,  
    Date, 
    CODE    
;   

Drop Table RawData; // this table is not needed anymore
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this! I do know about performance optimisation in QV and use incremental loads where possible... Unfortunately there are 2 issues with this data that I can't change though which means it's easier to process the whole dataset each day; data can come in for any date at any time (not sequentially) and we sometimes receive corrupt data from the machines that needs to be cleaned out. Lucky enough, I'm the only QV developer and the only one looking after the database so I can do the hard work wherever I like! ;-)